# How do you mirror (not flip) the screen horizontally in Windows?

Tags: screen

I tried UltraMon, didn't work.
I looked at every forum.
I Googled too.

Is there an app to do this? Please help me, don't ask me why I need to flip the screen.

Comment: I do not understand the question. More detail will increase your chance to get a better answer.

Comment: Voting to close as this doesn't appear to have anything to do with programming.